# Drupal 7 - Main menu not displaying

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Im having a bit of a problem with my theme, i have added the following code to page.tpl.php to display the main menu links, but nothing is showing.

```
$main = menu_navigation_links('main-menu', '1');
echo theme('links__system_main_menu', array(
    'links'         => $main,
    'attributes'    => array(
        'id'        => 'nav'
    ),
));
```

Could someone let me know where im going wrong.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
print theme('links__system_main_menu', array(
    'links' => $main_menu,
    'attributes' => array(
        'id' => 'main-menu',
        'class' => array('links', 'inline', 'clearfix'),
    ),
    'heading' => array(
        'text' => t('Main menu'),
        'level' => 'h2',
        'class' => array('element-invisible'),
    ),
));
```

Otherwise you can always place the menu throught blocks and regions.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are asking for a `depth (=1)` where you do not have any links.

Try `$main = menu_navigation_links('main-menu', '0');`

[Drupal 7 API about menu_navigation_links](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_navigation_links/7)